# How do I get the Facebook Like button to behave as documented and make its width 225px?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I'm surprised to find nothing else on the interwebs about this. Has anyone else noticed that the standard Facebook Like button will not get any narrower than 285px, despite Facebook's claim that the minimum width is 225px?

From
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/:

> layout - there are three options.
>
> standard - displays social text to the right of the button and
>   friends' profile photos below. Minimum width: **225 pixels**

Even their code generator/configurator creates an iframe preview that is at least 285 px wide when 225 px is selected as the width.

Despite my best efforts, I cannot get the width of the button under 285px. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Report bug in documentation.

As for the solution, use `<div />` container with `overflow: hidden`. Notice that there are different layouts that you can select, as well as, options, such as whether to show faces or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response! While your solution does allow me to constrain the like button to the width I want, it also cuts off the text on the like button. The iframe width is what I need to constrain, but it's generated by the XFBML I'm using. There actually is a bug registered (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/201145593299526 - thank you for the suggestion!), and it should be fixed soon. I'll report back when it is!

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can use combination of facepile and like button.